# matplotlib xkcd not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get the matplotlib xkcd function working, following this after installing all the necessary stuff. http://matplotlib.org/xkcd/examples/showcase/xkcd.html

every time I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph.py", line 4, in <module>
    plt.xkcd()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xkcd'
```

(I saved the code as graph.py)

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you show us your `import` line please? I suspect this is where you've gone wrong...

Comment: What version of ``matplotlib`` are you using? Have you tried updating to the latest one? **Edit**: ``xkcd()`` has been added in version 1.3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xkcd` module was added in [matplotlib 1.3.1](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#new-plotting-features). You need to update your version to that to get the xkcd examples to work properly.

Comment: Thanks. I had installed matplotlib using the Ubuntu ppa, which must have been lagging behind. I had to uninstall it and build from source, but now all is well. Thanks!